# If (in the far future) humans travel to other Star systems, how will Muslims be expected to pray?

Tags: salat, muslim-practices

This is just a hypothetical question I had. Let’s say in the future, humans build ships that can reasonably and quickly travel to other Star systems, across the galaxy. How would Muslims be expected to pray, since they’d be unable to see Earth at all?

Comment: Won't they be able to know in which approximate direction earth \ sun is located? Being able to see the earth is not a condition for prayer.

Comment: @UmH: the sun isn’t as bright a star as others, so it disappears after about >50 or so light years, unless you have a powerful telescope. Unless you mean they just pray in the general direction of the Star.

Comment: It is not required to be able to see anything in prayer. When I pray in my room I can not see the Kaabah, I just know in which direction it is located and face that.

Comment: This question has been asked and covered already on the site please search and you will find answers.